# how to add continuous citation ([15]-[20]) using a BibTeX file (.bib) in the IEEEtran

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am working on a paper that will be published in the IEEE. I am trying to add a continuous citation like this: [15]-[20] instead of [15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20].

I am using the following syntax for [15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]:

`\cite{Spacy} \cite{NLTK} \cite{text2emotion} \cite{lexicalrichness} \cite{textblob} \cite{core_nlp}`

However, when I try:
 `\cite{Spacy}-\cite{core_nlp}`
I get: [15]-[16] and not [15]-[20]

This is because I am using a .bib file and these citations only appear once in my paper.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Please be more specific ...

Comment: You need put all cite items inside a same `\cite`. Like `\cite{bib1,bib2,bib3,bib4,bib5}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all bib items under the same `\cite` like

```
\cite{bib1,bib2,bib3,bib4,bib5}
```

> Here I use `bibtex` with `cite` package, but the action is the same for `biblatex`.

Consider the following MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dumpy text
\usepackage{cite}
\title{IEEE Transactions on LaTeX}
\author{Teddy van Jerry, \IEEEmembership{Student Member, IEEE}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Cite Put Together}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{tipping2001sparse,wei2021channel,hu2018super,wang2012generalized,fang2015support}
Look they are continuous!
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv, ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

with bib file named `ref.bib`:

```
@article{tipping2001sparse,
  title   = {Sparse {Bayesian} learning and the relevance vector machine},
  author  = {Tipping, Michael E},
  journal = {J. Mach. Learn. Res.},
  volume  = {1},
  pages   = {211--244},
  month   = jun,
  year    = {2001}
}

@article{wei2021channel,
  title     = {Channel Estimation for {RIS} Assisted Wireless Communications--Part {II}: An Improved Solution Based on Double-Structured Sparsity},
  author    = {Wei, Xiuhong and Shen, Decai and Dai, Linglong},
  journal   = IEEE_J_COML,
  volume    = {25},
  number    = {5},
  pages     = {1403--1407},
  month     = may,
  year      = {2021},
  publisher = {IEEE}
}

@article{hu2018super,
  title     = {Super-resolution channel estimation for mmWave massive {MIMO} with hybrid precoding},
  author    = {Hu, Chen and Dai, Linglong and Mir, Talha and others},
  journal   = IEEE_J_VT,
  volume    = {67},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {8954--8958},
  month     = jun,
  year      = {2018},
  publisher = {IEEE}
}

@article{wang2012generalized,
  title     = {Generalized orthogonal matching pursuit},
  author    = {Wang, Jian and Kwon, Seokbeop and Shim, Byonghyo},
  journal   = IEEE_J_SP,
  volume    = {60},
  number    = {12},
  pages     = {6202--6216},
  month     = dec,
  year      = {2012},
  publisher = {IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{fang2015support,
  title     = {Support knowledge-aided sparse {Bayesian} learning for compressed sensing},
  author    = {Fang, Jun and Shen, Yanning and Li, Fuwei and others},
  booktitle = {Proc. {IEEE} Int. Conf. on Acoust., Speech, Signal Process. ({ICASSP})},
  pages     = {3786--3790},
  year      = {2015}
}
```

You will now have

[image: Result]